# Blank field in report viewer

Tags: c#, parameters, reportviewer, rdlc, visibility

HY! I have a form application and I use report viewer. I set some parameters, but when I want to display the fields, in my report I don`t see anything, only my header and footer and the parameters value, thus in my dataset I have values.

Here is my code:

```
        reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Dataset1", Dataset1.Tables[0]));
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Report1.rdlc";

        ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[4];
        parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("datastart",dateTimePickerStartRaport.Text);
        parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("dataStop", dateTimePickerStopRaport.Text);
        parameters[2] = new ReportParameter("TotalI", TotalI.ToString());
        parameters[3] = new ReportParameter("TotalD", TotalD.ToString());
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);    
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I don`t know where it is the problem. In an other report I do the same thing, but without using parameters and it works!

Is some visibility property or something when using parameters referring the fields displayed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between fields and parameters. Parameters must be declared in the Parameters-Section of the "Report Data"-window before they can be used and have a different syntax to access them in expressions. To use them in expressions, use the following syntax:

```
=Parameters![ParameterName].Value
```

In the expression-designer of VS you have a special category called "Parameters". If you build your expressions with the designer, you can select them there.

Comment: I do that, but I still see only the parameters and a blank report.

Comment: If you see the parameter-values in your report, I don't think that the problem is caused by the parameters. Otherwise, you would see parameter-based exceptions (such as parameter is not declared or parameter is declared but not provided). There is no special hiding-mechanism based on parameters. I would make a copy of the report, delete all than the Report Data definition and then add a table to see if the data is really available and if there is something wrong in the report definition. Then you know where to search.

Comment: the problem should be in the report view because there are the blank fields, but in my dataset the fields are not null. I encountered the same problem at sorting, i had the fields sorted in my dataset, but when it were displayed in the report it was not in the same order.